# wordpress keeps returning to main domain instead of subdomain after necessary changes

Tags: php, wordpress, subdomain

So, I'm doing redesign of a business portal and have copied DB, WP files,etc to subdomain and changed in DB table web url and home site, also changed the wp_configure.php file, and permalinks from dashboard. I log in to my subdomain successfully, but when I try to visit website on subdomain, it redirects me to main domain. I have no more clue were else should I look, or why is this happening. I provided SS, does anyone have any other idea what might be wrong here? All questions so far I found here don't have this kind of problem. 
 [image]

Comment: have you checked .htaccess?

Comment: can you post your htaccess code?

Comment: This is .htaccess I have:


<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>

Comment: your sub domain folder is inside the main domain fiolder?

Comment: no, its in public html as the main domain.

Comment: why are you putting `www` in your test site URL?  `www` is technically a subdomain, in and of itself. Try getting rid of that and that will most likely fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the WordPress Docs [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL#Changing_the_Site_URL) -

> 1. The "Site Address (URL)" setting ***is the address you want people to type in their browser*** to reach your WordPress blog.
> 2. The "WordPress Address (HOME URL)" setting is the address where your WordPress core files reside.

You need to reciprocate your current values; i.e, the value of `WP_SITEURL` should go in `WP_HOME` and vice versa. This will make the subdomain your site's url and will redirect users from your main domain to subdomain. If you want to completely remove main domain from pointing to your wordpress install. You'll need to set both `WP_SITEURL` & `WP_HOME` to your sub-domain and make necessary changes to your dns.

Comment: I did that, no changes. :(

Comment: Did you change the values in both, your `wp-config.php` and `DB`? Also ensure you clear cache if you use any caching plugins...

Comment: caching plugins are generally used for site content (scripts, images, etc).  they shouldn't have anything to do with hostnames, subdomains, or DNS.